`cmake --build build --target help` not showing all targets
I have a project that clearly defines the myapp.exe target in the toplevel CMakeLists.txt like this:
add_executable(myapp.exe src/myapp_main.cpp)

Now if I invoke the help target to list all the projects targets I get a huge list of targetst that I recognize as being defined somewhere, however myapp.exe is not in them:
cmake --build build --target help | grep myapp.exe
The strange thing is that cmake-tools for vscode correctly detects this target and lists it. What is the reason for this?

Which generator do you you use? Everything executed via cmake --build is generator-dependent.

Note also, that in CMake target name usually doesn't have "extension". So it is better to write add_executable(myapp src/myapp_main.cpp). If you want to rename the output file, then there is several target properties available, like OUTPUT_NAME.

@Tsyvarev You're right, I switched to "Unix Makefiles" and magically the target appeared. I thought this was the default, but it appears my generic cmake -S . -B build was using something else before

@Tsyvarev Unfortunately, this was not my naming decision :/
